# How To Switch b/w windows/dialogs in Autoit

Tags: autoit, scite

I have Two Windows I have to Switch b/w them

I tried the following code but not worked, here I tried to Simply Press Keyboard button ALT+TAB but does't work:

```
Send("! {TAB}")
```

or

```
Send("ALT} {TAB}")
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is to use WinActivate to activate each window each time you want. It's way more safe than use Send("!{TAB}").

[WinActivate](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinActivate.htm)

Comment: Also, to move to say third window when we will usually press Alt and press tab twice, the script to use is Send("! {TAB 2}")

Answer (score 0):

You have a space in the Send-command. And so you send: Alt+Space+TAB.
So it works:

```
Send("!{TAB}")
```

Comment: Where do you want to use this command, and from which application? Send is not the prefered command to work with windows. If you know the windows you want do switch, you can use WinActivate / WinSetState.

Comment: I tried this:  `Run("notepad.exe") 
Run ("MSPaint.exe")
 
 Local $hWnd = WinWait("[CLASS:Notepad]", "", 10)

 
 WinActivate($hWnd)`

And it's working Thanks

Comment: Alt Tab command works with windows but you need to be aware that its relative. The current window focus and the stack of windows will determine what the next window to focus will be. So use WinActivate to focus the first time, then from there use Send("! {TAB}") to move between windows.